# Is it possible to change the Column Heading of the 'Note Text' field in a grid

Tags: overriding, acumatica, dac

My client wants to see the Notes in a Grid column.

I can add the Note Text field of a record to a data grid - but our customer wants the column heading to read 'Internal Comment' instead of 'Note Text'
I have tried a DAC Extension on the PX.Data.Note but this does not work.
I am not sure how to use cache attached for this- because the Note_Text field seems to be added by the PXNoteAttribute ??

I have also tried this in the RowSelected event of the grid view - but it does not work:
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<Note.noteText>(this.Caches[typeof(Note)], Messages.InternalComment);

Any help appreciated

Comment: try your set display name in the graph constructor/initialization. If still doesn't work try adding a view to your graph for Note

Comment: You can try using translation from English to English and translate the "Note Text" into "Internal Comment" or another way will be to create a custom virtual field and return the note text and apply whatever label you want to it